# Regular expression in javascript for restricting HTML entites like &lt;

Tags: javascript, regex

Hii,

I want to restrict the html entities like `'&lt;' , "&gt;" , "&amp;"`etc but it should accept '<' and '>' when i click on a button
from the javascript. Can anybody gives me the regular expression for that

Comment: How about `&copy;`, `&#12345;`, `&#xabcd;` and ordinal text like `foo`? Do you just want to strip HTML tags like `<script>`? `<b>`?

Comment: No i want accept all the html tags but if it the content is in the encodeed format that should be avoided

Comment: So you want to *reject* the input if there's `&lt;`?

Comment: exactly,but should not reject '<' or '>'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updated regex for all entities, including numeric...

Javascript like:

```
var StrippedStr = YourStrVar.replace (/&#{0,1}[a-z0-9]+;/ig, "");
```

will strip just about every <strike>*non-numeric*</strike> html entity.

.

### UPDATE:

Based on comment:

```
   "but i want to identify the specified string contains &lt;"
```

.

You can **test** for entities with:

```
var HasEntity = /&#{0,1}[a-z0-9]+;/i. test (YourStrVar);
```

.

You can get a list of the entities with:

```
var ListOfEntities = YourStrVar.match (/&#{0,1}[a-z0-9]+;/ig);

for (var J=0;  J < ListOfEntities.length;  J++)
{
    alert ('Entity ' + (J+1) + '= ' + ListOfEntities[J]);
}
```

Comment: You can write `{0,1}` as `?`.

Comment: @Gumbo: True, but not my style.

Comment: Not your style? What is your style? You should always write your code as comprehensible as possible. Quantifiers like `?` and `+` were added for the same reason to not to be forced to write something like `(x|)` but simply `x?` and not `xx*` but simply `x+`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that?

```
function remove() {
  var buffer = document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML;
  buffer = buffer.replace(/'&lt;'/, "");
  buffer = buffer.replace(/'&gt;'/, "");
  buffer = buffer.replace(/'&amp;'/, "");
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML = buffer;
}
```

just adujst the id

Comment: It will replace the specified string to empty string, but i want to identify the specified string contains '&lt;'